# Организация вложенного цикла (?)

Tags: c#

День добрый! Прошу помощи.
Есть три листбокса.

Первый и второй листбокс как лучшие друзья. Т.е. для использования третьего нужно использовать одинаковые позиции первого и второго. (например items[0])

При нажатии на Button, должно быть так.
Берутся данные с двух первых листбоксов.

И делается дейтвие DoWork() 20 раз.
Каждый новый раз берутся СЛЕДУЮЩИЕ данные из третьего листбокса
тип items[0], items[0], items[I]

Когда проходит 20 раз по третьему берутся СЛЕДУЮЩИЕ данные с первых двух и следующие 20 из третьего items[1] items[1] items[I].

Как это организовать кодом?
P.S пробовал делать всякие приколюхи с Foreach - неудача.

Comment: Вопрос получает приз "самая ужасная формулировка года".

Comment: Тут надо на гадальных картах правильный ответ искать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a3.Items.Count; i++)
{
   int k = i / 20; 
   DoWork(a1[k], a2[k], a3[i]);
}
```

Comment: Эмм. Совсем не то

Comment: 20 элементов по порядку должны браться с третьего листбокса

Comment: При этом позиции первого и второго - совпадать. И выполнятся это должно до тех пор, пока все элементы третьего листбокса не будут обработаны

Comment: @crystal оно и возьмет 20 элементов по порядку из 3-го листбокса. индексы будут `0,0,0`, `0,0,1`,... `0,0,19`, `1,1,20`, `1,1,21`.... `1,1,39`, `2,2,40`... - точно как у вас в вопросе

Comment: @crystal а если у вас в вопросе не так (или должно быть не так) - потратьте время и сформулируйте его по человечески. чтобы не было приклюх.

Comment: Все таки получилось. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы это имеете ввиду? (Код java-подобен)

a1 - лист 1
a2 - лист 2
a3 - лист 3

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        DoWork(a1[i], a2[i], a3[j]);
```

Comment: Да, но когда пройдет 20 иттераций - программа выполнится.

Comment: А в Listbox3 может быть 100 айтемов. Следовательно нужно выполнить все это пять раз

Comment: А может быть и 200. А может быть вообще числом которое не делится нацело на 20.